# Does Stackless Coroutine really require extra compiler support?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

According to https://medium.com/yandex/c-23-is-finalized-here-comes-c-26-1677a9cee5b2 `Stackless coroutines require compiler support and can’t be implemented on their own as a library.` is it true?

Didn't `CO2` https://github.com/jamboree/co2 already implement stackless coroutine?

Comment: As noted on the repo itself, it is a partial implementation with significant limitations.

Comment: Most notably that library forces you to declare all your local variables at the top of the function. I've made [a similar library](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/rcoro) without that limitation, but ultimately the macro syntax is going to suck, one way or another.

Comment: Ewww, it's like the olden days using setjmp/longjmp before we had throw/catch.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement "stackless coroutines" in a library in about the same way as you can [implement lambdas](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/lambda.html) in a library or that you can implement virtual functions in C. You *technically* can do it, and it may even work well in some cases. But it'll come with dozens of irritating and fragile requirements and ultimately will still be beaten by the real language feature in most cases.

For example, the library you cited requires that you list all of the variables you need to have preserved across suspend points. It also requires you to use special syntax if a suspend point happens to be inside of a `switch`. Both of these make the feature quite brittle; adding a variable in one place but not the other, or throwing a suspend point in the wrong place, can *silently* break your code (ie: it compiles, but will fail at runtime... at some point, in some way). The actual language feature does not care; it just works.

So the statement is wrong in the strictest sense. But the general gist of it is accurate enough.